# Webcam capture on Mac OSX 10.7 - QucikTime/QTKit/AV Foundation

Tags: macos, webcam, qtkit

I'm new to Mac programming and am really getting confused on what is the correct way to capture any webcam.

**Learnt:** 
On Windows - Directshow filters are the only recommended way.
On Mac, there are atleast three frameworks. This is what I've understood by searching through the forums. Please correct me if I am wrong.
*QuickTime* - 32 bit applications only
*QTKit* - 64 bit applications only
*AV Foundation* - OS X 10.7 and above.
(I've gone through some posts which said - when QTKit is used, some webcams were not even recognized. But did't understand what to do)

**Requirement:** Capture any Webcam (internal or external - any vendor) on Mac OS X 10.7 and above in a 64 bit application, which is built on OS X 10.6 (due to large chunk of frameworks not migrated to Xcode 4 at the current moment code has to be built on Xcode 3.2.5 on OS X 10.6. We are planning to migrate to Xcode 4, but it takes more time and cant fit it in the current release schedule). So, I cant use AV Foundation.

**Question:** If we use QTKit alone, will the application be able to capture all webcams? Or some webcams with 32 bit drivers or drivers which support only AV Foundation fail? Is the right way to capture on Mac is to implement the capture functionality using all three frameworks?